# Adding a collection to an existing document in Firestore

Tags: ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add a song to an album collection but I do not know how to access the document ID within the album collection. I have got so far with the code below but how does one access the doc id and represent it as a string. I want my database to as such:

Band > Album > Song

So that each band can have multiple albums and each album can have multiple songs. What do I reference in the .doc() for the albums collection?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
//Allow user to append a song to an album.
  createSong(value){
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        this.afs.collection('band').doc(currentUser.uid).collection('albums').doc().collection('songs').add({
            title: value.title,
            description: value.description
          })
          .then(
            res => resolve(res),
            err => reject(err)
          )
        })
        //console.log(value.id);
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You seem to have issues finding an answer. It might help to edit your question to clarify your problem description. In addition you might want to add more tags (e.g. like `angular` or `sass`). For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Taking the tour helps as well